Will a monolayer rise (or sink) in water?
I'm aware of the principles by which an air bubble rises in water .  But what happens when a flat monolayer is placed beneath the surface, perfectly perpendicular to local gravity?
Is there still sufficient change in the density of water over one atomic radius (roughly)  to allow the monolayer to rise or fall, depending on whether the molecular weight is less or greater than that of water?   Do van der Waals forces dominate?

It seems unlikely to remain a monolayer for very long, between the general instability of a monolayer and the shear forces of water trying to get around the monolayer. More likely to ball up and then rise.
